# Setting up timezones in mysql

Tags: mysql, timezone

I'm a MySQL/WAMP newbie attempting to set up timezones so that I could follow along with a course on the topic, but then I started having troubles when the instructions I was being given didn't correspond to the info on the MySQL page from which I was to download the setup file, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html.

Can anyone tell me why, when I attempt to run this command from the mysql command prompt:

```
 mysql -u root mysql < C:/timezone_posix.sql;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
```

BTW, I've tried that with both forward and backward slashes, with and without quotes, etc., from my WAMP 5.6.17, MySQL command prompt, and the file in question is the posix (not isam) version that corresponds to the MySQL version on a windows machine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We can best help you with your problem when you focus on what you're trying to achieve and the specific error you're encountering, I've cleaned up your question accordingly.

Comment: You shouldn't run that from the mysql command prompt, you should run it from the cmd.exe prompt.

Comment: Gosh, thanks Brad, but by removing the link to the image which showed the error, cutting out the part where I explained the problem and asked the question about it, you destroyed the original purpose for the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be running that from the regular command prompt, not inside the mysql program, since it runs the mysql program. So it should be at the `C:\` prompt.

Or you could use the mysql `source` command to read from a file:

```
mysql> use mysql
mysql> source 'C:/timezone_posix.sql'
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, Barmar. Actually, I had determined that something was wrong & 1st tried the cmd in the dos prompt (it wasn't recognized) and then figured out that source might help.   I attempted what you suggested, and got minutes of beeping and pages of this:ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected.  I think it found my file (the orig. from MySql link above) and yet didn't seem to know where the database was...maybe.  It still shows me near zero length timezone files in: \wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\mysql dir.

Comment: You need to select the `mysql` database with `use mysql`

Comment: How did you get into the `mysql>` prompt if the `mysql` command isn't recognized?

Comment: yeah, again, total newb at this.  I got the command prompt from the WAMP sys tray icon's pop-up menu.  any thoughts on why it bleeped and gave me screens of err. 1046?

Comment: OK.   Barmar, I see you also said to do a "use mysql".  not surprizingly, that didn't work.  after more play, I decided to remove the ticks, and voila!  it worked.  thank you.

Comment: Just a minor problem: it should be `mysql> source C:/timezone_posix.sql` where there are no quotes around the file directory path.